# Write log for curl on windows

Tags: curl, vbscript

I currently have a script that runs a `curl` function to fetch files from another server, i am trying to debug some issues with this script and would like to enable logging for this `curl` function.

I have read that this can be achieved using the `--trace` file switch.

Can someone help me add this functionality to the below code?.

The log must be unique for each `curl` call, perhaps using the date/time call?

The script has the following variables defined:

```
strCodeBase = "E:\WebApps\LogHarvest\curl-7.40.0-win32\bin\"
strScriptSource = "LogHarvest.vbs"
strServerDir = "\\server.contoso.com\WebLogs\test\"

'  Determine current date, then calculate date-1 and separate Day, Month, and Year.
strDate = Date
strDate = DateAdd("d",-1,strDate)
strDay = Day(strDate)
strMonth = Month(strDate)
strYear = Year(strDate)

'  Get the two digit representation of the year.
strShortYear = Right(strYear,2)

'  For day numbers less than 10, append a leading 0.
If strDay < 10 Then
    strDay = "0" & strDay
End If

'  For month numbers less than 10, append a leading 0.
If strMonth < 10 Then
    strMonth = "0" & strMonth
End If
```

The test folder contains folders with server names such as server2.contoso.com and server3.contoso.com

I have updated the code with the suggestions provided below, i now get an error

E:\WebApps\LogHarvest\basic.vbs(94, 3) (null): The system cannot find the file s
pecified.

Line 94,3 is : objShell.Run strcURL,,true

```
'  Build the cURL command line.
strcURL = chr(34) & strCodeBase & "curl" & chr(34) & " -s -f --trace " & strTraceFile & " -o "
strcURL = strcURL & chr(34) & strServerDir & strServer & "\gr" & strShortYear & strMonth & strDay & ".zip" & chr(34) & " "
strcURL = strcURL & "http://" & strServer & "/weblogs/gr" & strShortYear & strMonth & strDay & ".zip"

'Echo to see strcURL
Wscript.Echo strcURL
```

The echo returns

```
"E:\WebApps\LogHarvest\curl-7.40.0-win32\bin\curl" -s -f --trace trace20150211191943.log -o "\\server.contoso.com\WebLogs\test\server2.contoso.com\gr150210.zip" http://server2.contoso.com/weblogs/gr150210.zip
```

Running the above command from cmd runs ok, suggesting that the script is failing elsewhere.

```
Private Function FunDateTime( byVal dtmDateTime)
' input: any value of (or convertible to) 'date' TypeName
' returns YYYYmmddHHmmss string (14 chars)
FunDateTime = YEAR( dtmDateTime) & _
  Right( "00" & Month( dtmDateTime), 2) & _
  Right( "00" & Day( dtmDateTime), 2) & _
  Right( "00" & Hour( dtmDateTime), 2) & _
  Right( "00" & Minute( dtmDateTime), 2) & _
  Right( "00" & Second( dtmDateTime), 2)
End Function
'
' Examples:
' FunDateTime(  Now) returns YYYYmmddHHmmss 
' FunDateTime( Date) returns YYYYmmdd000000, i.e. HHmmss   == 000000
' FunDateTime( Time) returns 18991230HHmmss, i.e. YYYYmmdd == 18991230
' FunDateTime(  365) returns 19001230000000, i.e. 365 days since above date
' FunDateTime( "xy") results to 'Type mismatch' runtime error
```

Comment: Is your question primarily on `curl` _how-to_, or on `vbscript` _how-to_?

Comment: I would say a vbscript how-to

Comment: What about the output from `wscript.echo strcURL`? Please [add examples to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28229160/edit): how does it look and how should it be.

Comment: That would run curl.exe contoso1.domain.com\w3svc01\gr150204.zip which would pull the file gr150204.zip into the current folder. 
A --trace switch would give me something like logfile.log, I would like curl to write this function to a logfile once it completes and then rename that logfile with the current timestamp so that it does not get overwritten on the next run

Comment: Not much more to say to that self-explanatory  `The system cannot find the file specified` message. That _the file specified_ is most probably `curl.exe` under the  `"E:\WebApps\LogHarvest\curl-7.40.0-win32\bin\"` directory... The `Run` expects provided string to be the same as if written in command line window.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing rightness of your code snippet (as I don't know content of `strCodeBase`, `strServerDir`, `strServer`, ... variables):

```
'  Build the cURL command line.
strTraceFile = "trace" & FunDateTime( Now) & ".txt"
strcURL = chr(34) & strCodeBase & "curl" & chr(34) _
    & " -s -f --trace " & strTraceFile & " -o "
strcURL = strcURL & chr(34) & strServerDir & strServer & "\gr" _
    & strShortYear & strMonth & strDay & ".zip" & chr(34) & " "
'Echo to see strcURL
Wscript.Echo strcURL 

Private Function FunDateTime( byVal dtmDateTime)
' input: any value of (or convertible to) 'date' TypeName
' returns YYYYmmddHHmmss string (14 chars)
FunDateTime = YEAR( dtmDateTime) & _
  Right( "00" & Month( dtmDateTime), 2) & _
  Right( "00" & Day( dtmDateTime), 2) & _
  Right( "00" & Hour( dtmDateTime), 2) & _
  Right( "00" & Minute( dtmDateTime), 2) & _
  Right( "00" & Second( dtmDateTime), 2)
End Function
'
' Examples:
' FunDateTime(  Now) returns YYYYmmddHHmmss 
' FunDateTime( Date) returns YYYYmmdd000000, i.e. HHmmss   == 000000
' FunDateTime( Time) returns 18991230HHmmss, i.e. YYYYmmdd == 18991230
' FunDateTime(  365) returns 19001230000000, i.e. 365 days since above date
' FunDateTime( "xy") results to 'Type mismatch' runtime error
```

[Resource](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html): To get even more details and information on what curl does, try using the `--trace` or `--trace-ascii` options with a given file name to log to, like this:

```
    curl --trace trace.txt www.haxx.se
```

Comment: There are _important_ underlines `_` ending some lines in the code

Comment: JosefZ, Thanks for the reply. I tried adding your code to my script , it throws the below error:

`code`
logharvest.vbs(206, 39) Microsoft VBScript compilation eror: Syntaxerror
`code`

Which is 
FunDateTime = YEAR( dtmDateTime) &

Comment: 1. **Please** do not post code snippets in comments. It becomes a bit unreadable as you could see yourself... [Update your question instead](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28229160/edit). 2. Nobody can help you don't knowing _all_ used variables content (see my answer). For help with this, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 3. Post result from `Wscript.Echo strcURL`

Comment: Josef, I have updated my question with the variables that were missing, i hope it makes more sense now, i am however not able to get the output for the Echo since the script is failing before the echo. 
<ul>
- Should the Private Function come before the curl code? 
- Also the curl syntax would be "curl domain --trace tracefile" in that order, i believe.

Comment: All the `Function` .. `End Function` definition code could be placed anywhere in your script, but under next **important** and **crucial** condition: You cannot define a `Function` procedure inside any other procedure (e.g. `Sub` or `Property Get`). Otherwise you get that  _Microsoft VBScript compilation error: Syntax error_. HTH

Comment: JosefZ, i have updated the question with the error which i am getting now, i made changes in the code as per your suggestions. . .